# Bind input box value to data set

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ng-repeat to display a list of items, each of which has a line number, an html input box for quantity, and and itemId. I'm trying to figure
out how to bind the value that I enter into the input box to the quantity field in the myItem object.

```
<tr ng-repeat="myItem in selectedItems track by $index">
<td>
    {{ myItem.lineNumber }}.
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" size="8" ng-blur="showAllItems()" ng-bind="myItem.qty" ></input>
</td>
<td>
    {{ myItem.itemId }}
</td>
</tr>
```

As you can see, I've got an ng-blur method being called to display all of the items. This is the method:

```
$scope.showAllItems = function() {

angular.forEach($scope.selectedItems, function(value,key) {
    console.log("key = " + key + ", value.lineNumber = " + value.lineNumber + ", value.qty = " + value.qty + ", itemId = " + value.itemId);

});

}
```

This is how I know the qty value isn't binding with my data set. What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`ngModel` is the answer:

```
<input type="text" size="8" ng-blur="showAllItems()" ng-model="myItem.qty" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need use ngModel attribute `ng-model="myItem.qty"`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, that was it! I had to use ng-model instead of ng-bind.